# Independent random variables and Expectation

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, independence

So, I know that if two random variables X and Y are independent, then E(X|Y) = E(X).
And I read that the inverse of this statement may not be necessarily true. ie. E(A|B) = E(A) but A and B are not independent. But I can't think of a situation where this happens.
So if this is right, can you give an example where this is possible?

Comment: $X \sim N(0,1), Y=X^{2}$.

Comment: @Luna, Mr. K.R.Murthy just gave an counterexample to what you're asking now. It says that even if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, $E(X|Y) = E(X)$ is quite possible.

Comment: oopsss right, sorry XD